# Jquery - Slide panel to rightby X pixels

Tags: jquery, mobile, user-interface

I'm working on a mobile UI. It's a hybrid app, Html5, CSS3, Jquery etc.

You might have seen some mobile apps where there is a panel to the right or left of the "screen" thats exposed on a user interaction. These will slide right or left etc.

I've found the code to slide a panel down with toggle. I've also seen the code to slide a panel all the way across the screen.

Q, How to I slide a panel from left to right but say only 50px. Pushing the original panel to the right by those 50px? This needs to be a toggle as well.

UI example: http://edi.io/wires/mobile/Home.html

Thanks for the help.